# Write columns of different dataframe/np.array in external files - Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I am stacked with something that should be very easy to realize. 
I have a panda data frame where each column (in total 10000) represents my x-variable. I have also another panda data frame that is my y-variable and it is composed by one column only.
I would like to create external files where I can find in file0->[y,x[0]], in file1->[y,x[1]], etc. etc. 
At the beginning I though to put everything together in one only file by concatenating the variables:
`new=pd.concat([time['#Time'],lc], axis=1)
new.to_csv('simulated_lc.csv', sep=' ',index=False)`

but with 10000 columns it is not so pratical to use then the data file.

I also tried with another approach: instead of putting my variables inside a dataframe, I defined them as array. So, I have the x-variable that is x[i,j] where each i-row is the dataset that I want to write in the i-file together with the y-variable that is a one-dimensional array:

```
for i in range(0,10000):
fname='lc'+str(i)+'.txt'
dataset=[x[i],y]
np.savetxt(fname,dataset)
```

The only problem I have is when I open the file the data are not written as two separate columns, like:

```
0 1
2 3
3 4
...
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: OK, if I have a wish I would like you to indicate not only the desired output, but also the actual output. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
z = x.join(y, lsuffix='L', rsuffix='R')
for i in range(0,1000):
    fname='lc'+str(i)+'.csv'
    z.to_csv(fname, index=i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `pd.concat` across a loop of *X's* columns using double bracket slicer, `[[...]]`:

```
for col in x.columns:
   fname='lc'+str(i)+'.txt'

   dataset = pd.concat([y, x[[col]]], axis=1)
   dataset.to_csv(fname, sep=' ', index=False)
```